# Unable to Fetch specific field from Mongodb using .find() Synatx ( Newbie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am newbee .Here is My Code. Bacically I am storing my jwt in  Mongo DB and it is getting Properly stored. When I am trying to fetch that token to verify it. I am unable to fetch that token. And console.log(find_refreshtoken) is showing [unexpected data](https://pastebin.com/0vaFrRXm) instead of showing token.  I want to fetch only tooken from this data.
Please help me. Thanks.

```
{
    _id: 621df700e560c645664a5b8a
    tooken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NDYxMzA5NDQsImV4cCI6M..."
    user: 620cc33a4776c82d2f636399
    createdAt: 2022-03-01T10:35:44.270+00:00
    __v: 0
}
```

code Goes Here:

```
verifyRefreshToken: (refreshToken) =>{
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            JWT.verify(refreshToken,process.env.Refresh_Token_Secret,(err,payload)=>{
                if(err)return reject(createError.Unauthorized())
                const userId=payload.aud
                const find_refreshtoken= RefreshTokenModel.find({"user":userId},{"tooken":1,"_id":0});
                console.log(find_refreshtoken);
                if(!find_refreshtoken){
                    reject(createError.InternalServerError())
                    return
                }
                if(find_refreshtoken === refreshToken){
                    console.log(find_refreshtoken);
                    return resolve(userId)
                }else{reject(createError.Unauthorized())} //It is executing this part
                
                //resolve(userId)
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to read the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

The `find` method return a [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html)  which means it is **expected data** not as you claim **unxepected data**.

So in order for your code to work just change:

```
const find_refreshtoken = RefreshTokenModel.find({"user":userId},{"tooken":1,"_id":0});
```

to:

```
const result = await RefreshTokenModel.find({"user":userId},{"tooken":1,"_id":0}).exec();
```

or even better use `findOne`, since you only want one i suppose:

```
const result = await RefreshTokenModel.findOne({"user":userId},{"tooken":1,"_id":0}).exec();
```

Comment: thanks for sending me to docs. As await needs aync so I used  ``` RefreshTokenModel.find({"user":userId},{"tooken":1,"_id":0},(err, result)=> {} ``` and it worked for me. Again verry verry thank you sir.